# Using diagnostic_updater in a ros2_control resource (actuator etc)

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

In ROS 1 I use an `diagnostic_updater::Updater` to publish hardware infos like status/error words, current device mode etc.
The usage is pretty straight forward like creating the diagnostic Updater in my RobotHW instance and registering a `updateDiagnostics(diagnostic_updater::DiagnosticStatusWrapper& stat)` method for each hw component to it.

Doing this in ros2_control resource like an Actuator etc. seems to be not that easy.
The Updater ctor now needs a NodeT https://github.com/ros/diagnostics/blob/foxy/diagnostic_updater/include/diagnostic_updater/diagnostic_updater.hpp#L366
which makes sense since it needs to create the publisher.

My actuator is define like `class RobotMotorActuator : public BaseInterface<ActuatorInterface>` - so no access to a NodeT. I was thinking if I can get somehow the NodeT of the ControllerManager which I guess is actually the node loading my driver with the ResourceManager but I did not find a way to retrive it (for a reason? :) )

Maybe there is now a different best pratice. As an alternative I'm thining about a bunch of own StateInterface definitions and perform the Diagnostics in the controller.

Long story short - what is the intended way of bringing hardware diagnostic informations to the diagnostics 'subsystem' in ros2_control?

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380426/using-diagnostic_updater-in-a-ros2_control-resource-(actuator-etc)/) by [Webadone](https://answers.ros.org/users/72129/webadone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2021-06-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Maybe there is now a different best pratice.

well, it was actually never a best practice to publish directly from `hardware_interface`s. It was possible, but afaik the idea was always to have controllers publish and subscribe (ie: do all the non RT safe things).

> As an alternative I'm thining about a bunch of own StateInterface definitions and perform the Diagnostics in the controller.

exactly, this would be the preferred way.

This is not specific to diagnostics information though. Controllers (or these days also Broadcasters) should be used to interact with the ROS-side.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Webadone](https://answers.ros.org/users/72129/webadone/) on 2021-06-16**:
Thanks for your quick reply! Yes understood, that makes of course sense to me.